# issue in custom title bar (android)

Tags: java, android

when i customize title bar in view by adding a image, i face an issue as the images is not fixed to the edges accurately. I have attached the image where you can see space between the window margin and image added. How to overcome this problem. Below are the code that i have used to customize the title bar. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

java code :

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
 setContentView(R.layout.home_view);
 this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.upwindow);
```

layout code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="32dp">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/up_bar"
         android:src="@drawable/up_bar" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/pagename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Sify MyStorage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create style xml in values  folder :

```
<resources>
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground" /> 
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowTitleSize">32dp</item> 
 <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground
 </item> 

</style>
</resources>
```

then refer it in manifest  as :

```
 android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

this will solve it .

hope this help .

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different images for different resolutions? It might be that your image simply does not fit that space, and that you need a larger one. Be careful though, you might run into issues with your app working across different platforms with scaling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to play a little with styling in order to override this behavior. Define a custom theme (style) as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="customTitle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/up_bar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/customTitle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and then use this theme in your activity by applying `android:theme="@style/myTheme"` to your desired **activity** tag in *AndroidManifest.xml*

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and setBackground to your layout in layout file...

Like,,,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:orientation="vertical"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:background="@drawable/up_bar" <---Add this
     android:layout_height="32dp">
```

and `Remove imageview from xml`